# django admin related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I got these Models:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Media(models.Model):
  the_image   = FilerImageField(null=True)
  title       = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
  alt_text    = models.CharField(verbose_name="Alt Text", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

  created     = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
  modified    = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, auto_now=True)

  product_image_gallery   = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name="product_image_gallery", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Product's Image Gallery")

  def __str__(self):
     return self.the_image.__str__()

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Product( models.Model ):
  name    = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255)
  slug    = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", max_length=255, unique=True)
  price       = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Price', null=True, blank=True)
  sale_price  = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Sale Price", null=True, blank=True)
  sku = models.CharField(verbose_name="SKU", max_length=255)

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.sku, )
```

I have these Admin Objects:

```
class Media_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  search_fields       = ['id', 'the_image', 'title', 'product_image_gallery__sku']
  list_display        = ['the_image', 'image_tag', 'title', 'product_image_gallery', 'created']
  readonly_fields     = ('image_tag',)
  fieldsets = [
    ( "Data", {
        'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
        'fields': ['the_image', 'title', 'alt_text']}),
  ]
admin.site.register(Media, Media_Admin)
```

The `list_display` works fine but the search always gives an error saying:

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I use double underscore for the SKU `product_image_gallery__sku`, but it still gives an error, I tried `product_image_gallery` it is also an error.

My Trace:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mooimom_id/media/?q=A7005

Django Version: 1.10.7
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['corsheaders',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'tinymce',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'filer',
 'mptt',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
 'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'mooimom_django.mooimom_middleware.SimpleMiddleware',
 'ratelimitbackend.middleware.RateLimitMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
 42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
 185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
 544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1543.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self,

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in __init__
78.         self.queryset = self.get_queryset(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in get_queryset
  346.         qs, search_use_distinct = self.model_admin.get_search_results(request, qs, self.query)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_search_results
  905.                 queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
   1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
   1247.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
   1178.             lookup_class = field.get_lookup(lookups[0])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in get_lookup
   694.             raise TypeError('Related Field got invalid lookup: %s' % lookup_name)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/mooimom_id/media/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

Comment: Do you have a better trace? Need more context of the error.

Comment: added more trace

Comment: `product_image_gallery__sku` (with double underscore) should work, since `sku` is a CharField. `product_image_gallery` won't work. So I'm a bit at lost why you get the error. Side note: related_name is for the reverse relation (from product to media), so you'd better set it to `media`

Comment: exactly, it should work. But i keep getting error, i believe it's probably because product_image_gallery can be null in the Model object

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the error is because of

```
search_fields       = ['id', 'the_image', 'title', 'product_image_gallery__sku']
```

"the_image" is a FilerImageField object, it causes the error.

It works when i turned it into:

```
 search_fields       = ['id', 'title', 'product_image_gallery__sku']
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to clarify on why this error occured. You were trying the allow searching on `the_image`. But since this field is of type `FilerImageField` Django cannot provide an acceptable query for this kind of search.

***Behind the scene***

This is from Django documentation:

> When somebody does a search in the admin search box, Django splits the
>   search query into words and returns all objects that contain each of
>   the words, case insensitive, where each word must be in at least one
>   of search_fields.

Therefore, if you want to allow search, you probably want to add the field `title` instead, which I assumed is the name of the image. This way, people will be able to search image by their name.

Hope it helps !